# How can I see the websites visited by clients of my WLAN?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, proxy, sniffer

How can I view the websites that are visited by the user of my wifi? 
What tools are required to do this? And one more question: can I see the WhatsApp  communications?

Answer (score 4):

You can intercept the traffic by building a bridge between the AP and the uplink. This can be done by using the `bridgeutils` and two network interfaces.  The software side is described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections).

This will allow you to capture and view all traffic. You can then display the data in wireshark or use a transparent proxy to get the informations you want in a protocol specific way. You can use `squid` for http for example. It will not be possible to read encrypted traffic unless you have administrative privileges on the hosts that are connected.

You can also only display the DNS requests to gather information abour what hosts are resolved. This will not only include all hosts that are used as http servers but all hosts that are used by your clients.

When you have administrative privileges on the hosts connected you can install a fake CA certificate in the browsers and the OS list and then intercept the SSL connection using a tool like `mitmproxy` which is described [here](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/08/04/use-sslsplit-to-transparently-sniff-tls-ssl-connections/).

To be specific for whatsapp have a look at this [article](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/whatsapp-encrypted-messaging/) it will almost surely not work.

Comment: can suggest software according to the above description for windows

Comment: You mean a proxy that is running on windows hosts?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer with a WIFI adapter which supports promiscuous mode, you will be able to capture the WLAN traffic via [`aircrack-ng`](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/), which is available on a variety of platforms, including Windows.

Note that you will be able to see a connection to a particular site/service (e.g. WhatsApp), but not necessarily intercept the actual data. Most modern sites/services which require a password to access implement SSL/TLS encryption which will prevent you from seeing the contents of the messages.